# How to get id of text box which is loaded dynamically -jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically loading three text boxes in a page, I need to take id of text boxes when it is clicked.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../taxClass/getTaxClass",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var taxClassBOs = data.taxClassBOs;
        $.each(taxClassBOs, function (key, value) {
            $("#taxVatId").append('<div><label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="VatId">' + value.description + '</label></div><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="vatId" value=""placeholder="' + value.title + '" id="' + value.taxClassId + '" class="form-control" /></div>');
        });
    }
});
```

I have tried this code

```
$('input[type="text"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind the event with dynamically added elements. You can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this.

```
$('staticParent').on('click','input[type="text"]'function(){
```

[Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct, but since you are loading them dynamically, you need to delegate

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="text"]',function(){
                         var id = $(this).attr('id');
                         alert(id);
                    });
```

The reason you need to delegate is because if you attach the handler like

```
$('input[type="text"]').click(function(){...});
```

it will attach to only the **current** elements.

However, with delegation, it will apply the handler to all **current** and **future** elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation on dynamically added elements.

```
$('#taxVatId').on('click', "input[type="text"]", function(){
                         var id = $(this).attr('id');
                         alert(id);
                    });
```

Comment: it should come in single quote as like this 'input[type="text"]'

Comment: @KarthikeyanRaju. shud work on `double quotes` too, what the problem?